# How can I set the xml result to the nvarchar declaration in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have the following sql , what I want is the return of the select to be assigned to the @NewCor Nvarchar , but I can't make it work

```
  declare @NewCor nvarchar(max) 
   select  
  (select 'ID' as th for xml path(''), type),
  (select 'Cod'   as th for xml path(''), type),
  (select 'Nume'  as th for xml path(''), type)
union all         
select 
  (select p.id     as 'td' for xml path(''), type),
  (select p.cod           as 'td' for xml path(''), type),
  (select p.nume as 'td' for xml path(''), type)
from #TempCor p 
for xml path('tr')
```

Comment: what flavor of SQL is this? Oracle, MSSQL Server?

Comment: This is an MSsql Database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am so sure about the internal structure of your temp table, so you may need to tweak a few things to match your use case. But generally this should give you an idea of how to do that:

```
declare @NewCor nvarchar(max);
select CONVERT(xml, N'<table><tr><th>a</th><th>Cod</th><th>Nume</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr></table>') [type] into #TempCor;

;with [base] as (
    select top 1
        T.TR.value(N'(th)[1]', N'nvarchar(max)') as [1],
        T.TR.value(N'(th)[2]', N'nvarchar(max)') as [2],
        T.TR.value(N'(th)[3]', N'nvarchar(max)') as [3],
        0 [Order]
    from [#TempCor] [p]
    cross apply [p].[type].nodes(N'(/table/tr)') [T](TR)
    union all
    select
        T.TR.value(N'(td)[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'),
        T.TR.value(N'(td)[2]', N'nvarchar(max)'),
        T.TR.value(N'(td)[3]', N'nvarchar(max)'),
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY GETDATE())
    from [#TempCor] [p]
    cross apply [p].[type].nodes(N'(/table/tr)') [T](TR)
    where
        T.TR.value(N'(td)[1]', N'nvarchar(max)') is not NULL or
        T.TR.value(N'(td)[2]', N'nvarchar(max)') is not NULL or
        T.TR.value(N'(td)[3]', N'nvarchar(max)') is not NULL
), [rec] as (
    select N'<tr><th>'+[1]+N'</th><th>'+[2]+N'</th><th>'+[3]+N'</th></tr>' as [string], [Order]
    from [base]
    where [Order] = 0
    union all
    select [rec].[string]+N'<tr><td>'+[1]+N'</td><td>'+[2]+N'</td><td>'+[3]+N'</td></tr>', [base].[Order]
    from [rec] join [base] on [base].[Order] = [rec].[Order] + 1
)
select @NewCor=[string]
from [rec]
where [Order] = (select MAX([Order]) from [base]);
```

Basically:

- Extract the data from XML, so you get a normal SQL table
- The recursively combine the data
- Finally: Assign the outcome (which is where Order is maxed) to a variable

Comment: My question might not had been right , what i want is the result of that SQL this:
<tr><th>ID</th><th>Cod</th><th>Nume</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>MEMBRI AI CORPULUI LEGISLATIV, AI EXECUTIVULUI, INALTI CONDUCATORI AI ADMINISTRATIEI PUBLICE, CONDUCATORI SI FUNCTIONARI SUPERIORI</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>11</td><td>LEGISLATORI, MEMBRI AI EXECUTIVULUI SI INALTI CONDUCATORI AI ADMINISTRATIEI PUBLICE</td></tr>   to be a string not XML object

Comment: Uhm could you elaborate? My query would yield 'aCodNume123123', so all values connected, in one variable. How could anybody give you the result of that SQL query for your data, if nobody has your data?

Comment: Updated the answer according to your updated specification.

The query would now return '<tr><th>a</th><th>Cod</th><th>Nume</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>' for my sample data.